# `new Date()` parsing is format dependent

Tags: javascript, date

I was surprised to realize that

`new Date('2015-02-15')` and `new Date('02-15-2015')` return different results. One parses the date as midnight UTC time, the other is parsed as midnight local time. This is also true of the moment-timezone package.

Is there a way to parse these dates in a standard way, either using moment or the builtin Date?

Comment: 1) `new Date(string)` is very unreliable anf has a lot of "legacy features". 2) There are a few ISO specifications for dates, `new Date().toString()` shows one of them (that is reliably parsed)

Comment: In the case of YYYY-MM-DD, the [*TC39*](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/87) decided to break with ISO 8601 and parse it as UTC rather than local. As for DD-MM-YYYY, parsing is implementation dependent. You can parse them with any library by providing the format of the string to parse, or write a simple parse function (2 or 3 lines of code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing expected date string format to moment.js seem to return the same local timezone

```js
// Sun Feb 15 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0800
moment('2015-02-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD').toString()
// Sun Feb 15 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0800
moment('02-15-2015', 'MM-DD-YYYY').toString()
```

You can use `moment-timezone` package for standardizing the time into UTC for example

```js
// Sun Feb 15 2015 08:00:00 GMT+0000
moment('2015-02-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD').utc().toString()
// Sun Feb 15 2015 08:00:00 GMT+0000
moment('02-15-2015', 'MM-DD-YYYY').utc()toString()
```

Try it out: https://jsfiddle.net/wyopm3xu/